# React Native - Process 'command 'cmd'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Tags: android, tensorflow, react-native

I am getting this below error while executing command: **gradlew assembleRelease**. 
I have tried updating expo-cli, still not worked. installed and configured jdk, gralde, groovy. Still no result. Please suggest.

> Configure project :app

Installing unimodules:
 unimodules-core@5.1.2 from C:\Users\Srini\Workspace\React\newApp\MyReactNative\node_modules@unimodules\core
 unimodules-react-native-adapter@5.2.0 from C:\Users\Srini\Workspace\React\newApp\MyReactNative\node_modules@unimodules\react-native-adapter
 expo-av@8.1.0 from C:\Users\Srini\Workspace\React\newApp\MyReactNative\node_modules\expo-av
 expo-constants@9.0.0 from C:\Users\Srini\Workspace\React\newApp\MyReactNative\node_modules\expo-constants
 expo-error-recovery@1.1.0 from C:\Users\Srini\Workspace\React\newApp\MyReactNative\node_modules\expo-error-recovery
 expo-file-system@8.1.0 from C:\Users\Srini\Workspace\React\newApp\MyReactNative\node_modules\expo-file-system
 expo-font@8.1.0 from C:\Users\Srini\Workspace\React\newApp\MyReactNative\node_modules\expo-font
 expo-image-loader@1.0.1 from C:\Users\Srini\Workspace\React\newApp\MyReactNative\node_modules\expo-image-loader
 expo-keep-awake@8.1.0 from C:\Users\Srini\Workspace\React\newApp\MyReactNative\node_modules\expo-keep-awake
 expo-linear-gradient@8.1.0 from C:\Users\Srini\Workspace\React\newApp\MyReactNative\node_modules\expo-linear-gradient
 expo-location@8.1.0 from C:\Users\Srini\Workspace\React\newApp\MyReactNative\node_modules\expo-location
 expo-permissions@8.1.0 from C:\Users\Srini\Workspace\React\newApp\MyReactNative\node_modules\expo-permissions
 expo-sqlite@8.1.0 from C:\Users\Srini\Workspace\React\newApp\MyReactNative\node_modules\expo-sqlite
 expo-updates@0.1.3 from C:\Users\Srini\Workspace\React\newApp\MyReactNative\node_modules\expo-updates
 expo-web-browser@8.2.0 from C:\Users\Srini\Workspace\React\newApp\MyReactNative\node_modules\expo-web-browser
 unimodules-app-loader@1.0.2 from C:\Users\Srini\Workspace\React\newApp\MyReactNative\node_modules\unimodules-app-loader
 unimodules-barcode-scanner-interface@5.1.0 from C:\Users\Srini\Workspace\React\newApp\MyReactNative\node_modules\unimodules-barcode-scanner-interface
 unimodules-camera-interface@5.1.0 from C:\Users\Srini\Workspace\React\newApp\MyReactNative\node_modules\unimodules-camera-interface
 unimodules-constants-interface@5.1.0 from C:\Users\Srini\Workspace\React\newApp\MyReactNative\node_modules\unimodules-constants-interface
 unimodules-face-detector-interface@5.1.0 from C:\Users\Srini\Workspace\React\newApp\MyReactNative\node_modules\unimodules-face-detector-interface
 unimodules-file-system-interface@5.1.0 from C:\Users\Srini\Workspace\React\newApp\MyReactNative\node_modules\unimodules-file-system-interface
 unimodules-font-interface@5.1.0 from C:\Users\Srini\Workspace\React\newApp\MyReactNative\node_modules\unimodules-font-interface
 unimodules-image-loader-interface@5.1.0 from C:\Users\Srini\Workspace\React\newApp\MyReactNative\node_modules\unimodules-image-loader-interface
 unimodules-permissions-interface@5.1.0 from C:\Users\Srini\Workspace\React\newApp\MyReactNative\node_modules\unimodules-permissions-interface
 unimodules-sensors-interface@5.1.0 from C:\Users\Srini\Workspace\React\newApp\MyReactNative\node_modules\unimodules-sensors-interface
 unimodules-task-manager-interface@5.1.0 from C:\Users\Srini\Workspace\React\newApp\MyReactNative\node_modules\unimodules-task-manager-interface

> Configure project :react-native-tensorflow
>   WARNING: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
>   It will be removed soon. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html
>   WARNING: The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (26.0.1) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (28.0.3) for Android Gradle Plugin 3.5.3.
>   Android SDK Build Tools 28.0.3 will be used.
>   To suppress this warning, remove "buildToolsVersion '26.0.1'" from your build.gradle file, as each version of the Android Gradle Plugin now has a default version of the build tools.

The Kotlin Gradle plugin was loaded multiple times in different subprojects, which is not supported and may break the build.
This might happen in subprojects that apply the Kotlin plugins with the Gradle 'plugins { ... }' DSL if they specify explicit versions, even if the versions are equal.
Please add the Kotlin plugin to the common parent project or the root project, then remove the versions in the subprojects.
If the parent project does not need the plugin, add 'apply false' to the plugin line.
See: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:subprojects_plugins_dsl
The Kotlin plugin was loaded in the following projects: ':expo-error-recovery', ':react-native-webview'

> Task :app:bundleReleaseExpoUpdatesAssets

C:\Users\Srini\Workspace\React\newApp\MyReactNative>SET /P STOREDPATH= 0<"C:\Users\Srini.expo\PATH"

C:\Users\Srini\Workspace\React\newApp\MyReactNative>SET PATH="\"C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\iis express\PHP\v5.6;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.1;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Lenovo\Bluetooth Software\;C:\Program Files\Lenovo\Bluetooth Software\syswow64;C:\Users\srini\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.1;C:\Program Files\groovy-2.5.9\bin;C:\Gradle\gradle-6.4.1\bin;C:\Users\Srini.windows-build-tools\python27\;C:\Users\Srini\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Scripts\;C:\Users\Srini\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\;JAVA_HOME; $HADOOP_HOME; $HADOOP_BIN; $HADOOP_HOME/bin; $JAVA_HOME/bin;C:\Users\Srini\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\Srini.dotnet\tools;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\iis express\PHP\v5.6;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL
Server\150\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.1;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\""

C:\Users\Srini\Workspace\React\newApp\MyReactNative>expo bundle-assets C:\Users\Srini\Workspace\React\newApp\MyReactNative --platform android --dest C:\Users\Srini\Workspace\React\newApp\MyReactNative\android\app\build\intermediates\merged_assets\release\out
[19:39:31] Error: The manifest at 'C:\Users\Srini\Workspace\React\newApp\MyReactNative\android\app\src\main\assets\app.manifest' was empty or invalid.
[19:39:31] Before making a release build, make sure you have run 'expo publish' at least once. Learn more. (ΓÇïhttps://expo.fyi/release-builds-with-expo-updatesΓÇï)

> Task :app:bundleReleaseExpoUpdatesAssets FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:bundleReleaseExpoUpdatesAssets'.

  > Process 'command 'cmd'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.4.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 1m 34s
432 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 430 up-to-date

Comment: I got it too, just with another application.

Comment: add react native, expo version and add how to reproduce this issue?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, `finished with non-zero exit value 1` is a generic placeholder for Gradle build error. The real cause of the error is usually described above.

In this case it you have:

```
Error: The manifest at 'C:\Users\...\app.manifest' was empty or invalid.
[19:39:31] Before making a release build, make sure you have run 'expo publish' at least once. Learn more. (https://expo.fyi/release-builds-with-expo-updates)

Task :app:bundleReleaseExpoUpdatesAssets FAILED
```

So is you should:

- check that app.manifest is actually there and valid
- Make sure you've ran `expo publish` as indicated in the error message
- check the [link](https://expo.fyi/release-builds-with-expo-updates) from the error message for more info